# Winter Bash 2016!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Its official, the winter bash starts on December 19, 2016 and runs up till January 8, 2017.

I for one am super excited (again).

However my question to all of you is, do you want BSE to *not* have hats?
To quote the email from SE:

> If you want in, you don't need to do anything; that's the default this year, due to overwhelming positive response in previous years. **If you want to opt out, have someone on your team reply to this e-mail to say so by Tuesday, 13 December 2016**.

Comment: What is winter bash?

Comment: What is winter bash, you ask? Well you are in for some fun times. SE does this thing ([winter bash](http://stackpromos.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015)) every year, where you get "hats' for doing normal actions across the site. (example: edit your profile, or UV a old question)

Comment: All right, cool. Thnx!

Comment: YEPPPPPEEEEEYYYYY!!!!

Comment: David "Super" excited really??? best to join in I suppose or Gen. Prescott might shoot me.

Comment: @batFINGER sure. Last year I created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32836/davids-hat-store) just for the winter bash. I was tied for [first place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/manm3.png) in the great race to collect the most hats. I got **2** [Archimedes hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127/278094). I had 39 of the 41 hats. I have been looking forward to this years since last years ended, so yes I think it is safe to say that I am super excited. (Is it possible to be too excited for the winter bash?)

Comment: @David and here I thought I was special for getting just one Archimedes hat..... :(

Comment: I thought I was specially for having a life

Comment: Gimmie, gimmie, gimmie a sombrero... at least 1.5m in diameter.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LvDx.jpg) you go. :)

Comment: Dear santa StackExchange, please add a Mario hat this year. PLEEEEEASE!

Comment: wtf  VLC player has joined the bash and is wearing a santa hat???

Answer (score 6):

## Why on earth would anyone not want hats?

Everyone loves hats - they promote lots more activity on the site during a time when there would usually be less.

There is no need to ruin the fun for everyone just because of a few weird outliers - that is what the "I hate hats" button is for. This button is put in place for these poor, misguided souls to click on to ruin the fun only for themselves, instead of for everyone.

**Did I mention I like hats?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I, have no hats, but, upon hearing about this wonderfull "winter bash," I decided that I too would like to be an esteemed hat collector.

The only real question: Are helmets hats? Or are they not hats?

[image]

> Throughout history, men have worn hats as a way of showing how much better they are than other men. “I buy hats,” a behatted man seems to say. “I am better than you.”
>   In wartime, hats were a useful way of conferring rank, and ensuring that casualties were confined to the lower classes (hence the famous command of “Don't fire till you see the tops of their heads” at the Battle of Bunker Hill by William Prescott, a general renowned for only shooting enemy combatants who were poor). During peacetime, hats have been instrumental for men to let the non-hatted know just who is wearing the hat around here.

[image]
[image]